# Using exec vs import in python

Tags: python, django, settings

In django it's very common to use a `local_settings.py` file to supplement `settings.py` so that each machine can have different settings. Usually people do something like this.

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print "No local settings found!"
```

But the settings file usually contains large lists such as `INSTALLED_APPS`. If I want to add an app, I'd rather not copy the entire list into `local_settings.py` and modify it (makes for less readable code, and updating `settings.py` no longer affects any machine that re-writes `INSTALLED_APPS`). So I figured I could do something like this:

```
try:
    f = open('local_settings.py','r')
    exec f.read()
except IOError:
    print "No local settings found!"
```

Now `local_settings.py` no longer has to rewrite the entire `INSTALLED_APPS` variable:

```
INSTALLED_APPS.append('debug_toolbar')
```

I was under the impression that anytime you're using `exec` or `eval` you're probably doing something wrong. So my question is, is there anything wrong with this and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your desire to have modifiable defaults does not preclude the use of `import`.  Why do you think you need to use `exec` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my technique:

**settings.py**:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    sys.exit("FATAL: No local settings file found.")
```

---

**local_settings.py**

```
import settings

settings.INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_extensions',)
```

Comment: wouldn't this be a cyclical import? You can't import settings without importing local_settings without importing settings without...

Comment: I put the `try` statement at the bottom of `settings.py` so `INSTALLED_APPS` is already defined. That way you can also override settings (such as `settings.DEBUG = True`)

Comment: I switched over to this method (before my last comment) so I know it works. I just didn't understand how this avoids the cyclical import problem. Your comment explains this nicely, thank you. Very fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way: import `INSTALLED_APPS` in `local_settings.py`, copy it, then add to the copy:

```
import settings

INSTALLED_APPS = settings.INSTALLED_APPS[:] + ['debug_toolbar']
```